# Code analyzer for Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Has anyone come across a code analyzer that could be run on OS other than Mac to scan for Objective C (for iOS) code?

Comment: [LLVM/Clang](http://stackoverflow.com/a/563259/3714897)

Comment: I just noticed that Checkmarx is doing a pretty good job on Objective-C, too. FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OCLint](http://oclint.org/) works on Linux and OSX. It doesn't focus on security, but integrates with Clang, a static code analyser to do style and security at the same time. Of course, if you don't care about style you can just use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) to begin with! But if your code is tidy and readable, your security reviews will be a little less painful.

[Agnito](http://sourceforge.net/projects/agnitiotool/) also scans objective-C, and it costs $0, just like the other tools.

(I am not affiliated with these projects.)